# Updating Cookies using Javascript, stops after a few updates

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am trying to save my (WP gravity forms) form data into a cookie when the input is changed. So when the user comes back to the page, the fields that were populated before, are still filled with their details.

I am using the following code to save the data to a cookie:

```
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
}

jQuery('#myform').change(function(){
    var data = jQuery("#myform").serializeArray();
    var data2 = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(data2);
    setCookie('leadformData', data2, 30);
})
```

The code above works as expected. When I check a checkbox, and reload the page, the checkbox can be found as checked within the cookie.

**The problem**

When I enter the form, check/uncheck a few checkboxes and reload the page I can see the data is saved in the cookie

But doing this multiple times, it will stop saving the data to the cookie, but the data in the console.log is still correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I found out the total size of my cookie for the website was too big. So for the form I am using I cant use serializeArray for the form, and I will have to save only the data I really need to the cookie.